# confusing setup line with -f command

Tags: linux, bash

Please help me understand the second line .
I understand it adds the common library but I don't understand exactly what it does, specifically, the `[ -f ..` command

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -f ./scripts/commons.sh ] && source ./scripts/commons.sh ||
    { echo "Failed to source common.sh. Check that you are on l2ver dir." && exit 1; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-f` command checks if the file exits. `[]` is the test statement in bash.

`&&` ensures that the second command, `source ./scripts/commons.sh`  excecutes only if the first one successfully terminates. That is the file `./scripts/commons.sh` exists

eg if file exists

```
$ls test
test
$[ -f test ]
$echo $?
0
$[ -f test ] && echo "hello world"
hello world
```

if not

```
$[ -f test ]
$echo $?
1
$[ -f test ] && echo "hello world"
$
```

Answer (score 1):

`-f` tests that its argument exists and is a regular file (e.g., isn't a directory).

In the snippet you shared above, it checks if `./scripts/commons.sh` is a file, and then `source`s it code (i.e., executes it in **the same shell**).

Answer (score 0):

It means it the file `./scripts/commons.sh` exist
then if it exist the file will be processed by `source` command
[Read this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is the only one line due to logic expression.
The `-f` is a bash shortened test if the file exists. `source` command is responsible for getting the variables from `./scripts/commons.sh`.

You have an logic expression like: A and B or C. If `./scripts/commons.sh` does not exists, then error appears from echo and script terminates.

There are also many other bash built-in file tests. Please look at the list below:

```
       -b FILE
              FILE exists and is block special
       -c FILE
              FILE exists and is character special
       -d FILE
              FILE exists and is a directory
       -e FILE
              FILE exists
       -f FILE
              FILE exists and is a regular file
       -g FILE
              FILE exists and is set-group-ID
       -G FILE
              FILE exists and is owned by the effective group ID
       -h FILE
              FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
       -k FILE
              FILE exists and has its sticky bit set
       -L FILE
              FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)
       -O FILE
              FILE exists and is owned by the effective user ID
       -p FILE
              FILE exists and is a named pipe
       -r FILE
              FILE exists and read permission is granted
       -s FILE
              FILE exists and has a size greater than zero
       -S FILE
              FILE exists and is a socket
       -t FD  
              file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal
       -u FILE
              FILE exists and its set-user-ID bit is set
       -w FILE
              FILE exists and write permission is granted
       -x FILE
              FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
```